# ¿Cómo puedo validar si un input es vacío en Python?

Tags: python, string

Si tengo una variable con `input()`

```
entrada=input()

if len(entrada)==1:
   print("ingrese algo mas largo")
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer que dé el mismo mensaje pero si solamente el usuario presiona enter? Es decir, que sea un input vacío

Ya probé poniendo None y nada.

---

Pobre poniendo:

```
if len(entrada)==0
```

y me resultó pero aun así,no habrá alguien que pueda dar una respuesta mas técnica?
como referirse al vació?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo valido si una cadena es vacía en Python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/384337/c%c3%b3mo-valido-si-una-cadena-es-vac%c3%ada-en-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Las forma más Pythonicas de hacerlo es:

### Usando el if not

Es entendible y te ahorra usar `len()`. Basicamente en Python un string vacio se evalua como **False** (al igual que una lista vacia, un set, etc.) y si tiene algún contenido se evalua como **True***. Por lo que puedes crear un condicional que evalue dicha expresión.

```
entrada = input()

#Si entrada está vacio, se ejecuta el if
if not entrada:
   print("ingrese algo mas largo")
```

### Usando el or

Si no te importa imprimir el mensaje entrada, puedes usar un simple `or` que evalue la expresión. Esta forma es una de mis preferidas

```
entrada = input()
entrada or print("ingrese algo mas largo")
```

### Update

Como comenta @fedorqui puedes poner ambas condiciones, si quieres también capturar los que sean cero y uno.

```
entrada = input()

if len(entrada) <= 1:
   print("ingrese algo mas largo")
```

Comment: Ah, no me había dado cuenta de que también podia querer esa parte. Actualizo la pregunta con tú aportación. Gracias @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'

Answer (score 2):

Quizás te funcione:

```
entrada=input()

if (entrada.isspace() or len(entrada) <= 1):
   print("ingrese algo mas largo")
```

Si sólo te interesa que muestre el mensaje cuando la entrada es vacía o sólo contiene espacios en blanco, entonces los pones:

```
entrada=input()

if (entrada.isspace() or len(entrada) ==0):
   print("ingrese algo mas largo")
```