# ¿Cómo valido si una cadena es vacía en Python?

Tags: python, string

¿Tiene Python algo así como una cadena vacía de manera que puedas hacer lo siguiente?

```
if mi_cadena == string.empty:
```

Sea como fuera, ¿cuál es la manera más elegante de revisar si una cadena es vacía en Python? Se me hace raro mirar cada vez si la cadena es exactamente `""` y me da la sensación de que debe haber alguna manera más fácil.

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9573244/1983854

Answer (score 6):

Las cadenas vacías son ["falsillas"](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), lo que significa que se consideran falsas en un contexto booleano, por lo que puedes simplemente decir:

```
if not mi_cadena:
```

Esta es la forma preferida, si sabes que tu variable es una cadena. La recomienda de hecho [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), en la [sección “Programming Recommendations”](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations):

> For sequences, (strings, lists, tuples), use the fact that empty sequences are false.

Si tu variable puede ser de algún otro tipo, entonces deberías usar `mi_cadena == ""`.  Mira la documentación de [Evaluar como valor verdadero/falso](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) para otros valores que son falsos en contextos booleanos.

---

Para casos muy concretos puede ser preferible y más seguro usar: [`if "".__eq__(myString):`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55747410/1983854). Revisa el enlace para la explicación detallada.

Comment: Sería realmente valioso que incluyeras las explicaciones de "".__eq__(myString) que mencionas. Python tiene sutilezas que pueden ser desconcertantes.

Comment: @CandidMoe cierto. Hay sutilezas importantes en la explicación, así que me apunto hacerlo en breve tras digerir todo su contenido.